# Best way to time an OpenGL animation on OSX/iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, opengl-es

I have been experimenting with OpenGL on the Mac, using Mac specific OpenGL APIs, what is the best way to create an accurate animation loop?

Answer (score 2):

Use GLKit which is available since iOS 5 and takes away a lot boiler plate code you usually have to write for yourself. 
Particularly the game/animation loop stuff is handled by the framework. Basically you have to implement some delegate methods:

GLKViewControllerDelegate for updating vertices etc.:

```
- (void)glkViewControllerUpdate:(GLKViewController *)controller
```

GLKViewDelegate fro drawing:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

[This is good point to start reading.](http://38leinad.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/practical-blender-with-glkit-part-1-introducing-glkit/)

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac side you're probably used to using `CVDisplayLink` to synchronise with the vertical retrace. The iOS equivalent is `CADisplayLink` — it's basically the same functionality but responsibility is given to CoreAnimation rather than CoreVideo and the syntax differs slightly.

If you are willing to target iOS 5 exclusively then Kai's advice is probably best. Just use one of GLKit's new view controllers and all the stuff related to creating and wiring up a display link is handled for you.

Comment: I tried doing this, following the programming guide Apple released. But when I tried drawing inside the callback, the program crashed with exc_bad_access. It seems I can't do any drawing inside the function defined in: CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback()

Comment: `CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback` is on the Mac side. Also the callback you specify will be called on "a separate high-priority thread", so you probably want to use it just to post a message onto the main thread or wherever you've vested ownership of your OpenGL context.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no experience with mobile dev, but I guess the idea is the same as on a PC. The keyframe interpolation of animated models should be done each time you render your scene (if necessary, of course).